# How to Update Multiple Attribute With Struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

I was trying to make a function that can update user by given parameter.

**My Method:**

```
func UpdateMultiple(db *gorm.DB, user *User, id uint32) error {
    usr := User{}

    err := db.Debug().Model(User{}).Where("id = ?", id).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"email": user.Email, "is_active": false}).Take(&usr).Error
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

And Using like this:

```
Updater := &User{
    Email:    holder.Email,
    IsActive: false,
}
err = UpdateMultiple(s.DB, Updater, id)
```

It is working fine for now.But If want to update another field i have to change my *UpdateMultiple()* method. Is there any other way i can update without changing method but only changing given parameters value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your `User` model to the `Updates` function, it will update all struct fields with non blank value (which means that all fields should be pointers, in order to make the best use of this feature). The code would look like this:

```
func UpdateMultiple(db *gorm.DB, user *User, id uint32) error {
     return db.Debug().
          Model(User{}).
          Where("id = ?", id).
          Updates(user).Error
```

}

See some examples from the official documentation:

```
// Update multiple attributes with `struct`, will only update those changed & non blank fields
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "hello", Age: 18})
//// UPDATE users SET name='hello', age=18, updated_at = '2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id = 111;

// WARNING when update with struct, GORM will only update those fields that with non blank value
// For below Update, nothing will be updated as "", 0, false are blank values of their types
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "", Age: 0, Actived: false})
```

Comment: How do you update a field with blank value means null in database ?

Comment: @Eklavya you mean how to erase, set field as NULL in db?

Comment: Yes, may be then it ignores the update. That's it's quite risky.

Comment: @Eklavya then map[string]interface{} has to be passed to the `Updates` function. `"field_a": nil` will set it to NULL in db. That's a peculiarity of this approach, you have to specify explicitly when you want to set a field to NULL.

Comment: Yes, I know that's why I am not suggesting `non blank` field approach.

Comment: @Eklavya well, this way you make only one request to DB.

Comment: Have you tried this? I tried this before posting but it was only updating 1st Value Which is Email, I must have done some Mistake Maybe, Thanks For The Response

Comment: @MdArifulislamProtik as I mentioned in my answer, this methods updates only those fields that have non blank (non default) value. I your case, `IsActive` wasn't updated most likely because its value was `false`, which is the default (blank) value of `bool` type. As suggested, you should turn your struct fields into pointers to make the best use of the `Updates` func, because if the pointer is set (not `nil`), its value will be used even if it's the default blank value of the type (e.g. `false` for bool).

Answer (score 0):

Since you need dynamic field update, fetch user first by `id`

```
user := &User{}
db.First(&user, id)
```

Update the field you want to update

```
user.Email = "a@a.com"
user.IsActive = false
```

And update the user info

```
db.Save(&user)
```

Or

Create `map[string]interface{}` and add which field you want to update.

```
mp := make(map[string]interface{})
mp["email"] = holder.Email
mp["is_active"] =  false
```

And update the user

```
db.Model(User{}).Where("id = ?", id).Updates(mp)
```

Comment: I never thought of that. Thanks for Quick Response! Let me Try